# Sharing shared prefences between Activities and Services?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'd like to share the same key/value pairs between my Activities and my Services. As all have different contexts I assume that I need to share one specific context between all of them.

It can't be the context of any of the activities as a given activity may not in memory for all the time. (especially true as my background service launches at the phone startup so no activity exists at all until the user hits the app icon.)

I was thinking about creating a setter/getter for a static context variable in the class I'm using for reading/writing a context variable like this:

```
public class temp_shared_context {

public static Context ctx = null;

public static Context getCtx() { return ctx; }

public static void setCtx(Context ctx) { temp_shared_context.ctx = ctx; }
}
```

The issue I'm facing that when the appication starts the ctx is null and nobody can use the shared preference until the dedicated service uses the setter to write the ctx variable.

I have tried to change my getter like this:

```
    public static Context getCtx() {
    while (ctx == null) {}
    return ctx;
}
```

But this just makes my application hang.

What would be the right way to make sure to solve this problem? (maybe there is something lot more obvious than using setters/getters or singletons)

Comment: "I assume that I need to share one specific context between all of them." - Nope. Just call `getSharedPreferences()` with the same name `String` everywhere. Alternatively, use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` everywhere.

Comment: Ah, snap. You are right. I could swear that I have tried this and I got results suggesting that I really need to use the same context, but I was wrong. No matter which context I use I get the same result until I read the same name String.

Comment: Regarding the "wait until somebody writes first" part of the question, do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but if you need to signal one component from another that the data is written and ready, there are several different options; e.g., `Intent`s with `startActivity()`/`startService()`, broadcast `Intent`s with `LocalBroadcastManager`, some event bus implementation, a `ViewModel`/`LiveData`/Observer setup, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());` just like below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        sharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("variable", value);
        editor.apply();
```

and you can get the value wherever you want from your application like below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString("variable", "default_value");
```